# Qt equivalent to gtk_init_check

Tags: linux, qt

I need to check if an X session is up to return a value depending on that, so my application can decide to create windows.

In Gtk+2 there's `gtk_init_check`, which returns -1 if it can't connect to X session.

What is the equivalent for Qt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In complement of [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28528313/841108) mentioning `QGuiApplication`, and assuming Linux + [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System), you could in practice simply test that `getenv("DISPLAY")` returns a non-null string. You could also -and instead- use [XOpenDisplay](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/opening.html) (followed by `XCloseDisplay`)

BTW, I don't know how Qt works on non X11 displays, i.e. [Wayland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_%28display_server_protocol%29) or [Mir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mir_%28software%29).

Comment: :Thanks. My solution was to check DISPLAY env, but there's error once no display was present. Your solution about opening and closing display is what i was searching. I must write, that XOpenDisplay check DISPLAY variable present, when you pass NULL as first argument.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Qt does not work like that. You either

1. create a QGuiApplication (or QApplication if you are using widgets), and then it connects and validates that your X session is working prior to QApplication's constructor returning, or
2. create a QCoreApplication, and then you have no graphics available.

A QGuiApplication with default X subsystem (xcb) will issue an error `QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display` and issue `SIGABRT` from libqxcb. If you try to use different module, like `offscreen` using construct like,

```
your_application --platform offscreen
```

then the GUI application will start but you are no longer connected to X. If you wish to get X session info, look into X11Extras module,

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qx11info.html

Remember, if you are using QCoreApplication or not connected to X, this will return `nullptr` for X connection information since you are not connected to X server.